# The button only responds to one click, the next ones do nothing

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel

I`m building an app where I can click a Image and add a border to this image. I did it and when i click for the first time, the border changes, but second click does nothing.

[image: App Visualization]

The buttons on the bottom draw a new dice, and set dice border to no border.
I am saving a state in mutableListOf

Main Screen and Dices Composables:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val viewModel = viewModel<DicesViewModel>()
    val dice = viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()

    Column {
        Dices(dice = dice.value.dices, isSelected =  dice.value.isSelected, onClick = { viewModel.isSelectedBehavior() })
        Buttons(onTurnClick = { viewModel.drawDice()  }, onQueueClick = { viewModel.drawDice() })
    }
}

@Composable
fun Dices(@DrawableRes dice: MutableList<Int>, isSelected: MutableList<Boolean>, onClick: (Int) -> Unit) {
    Column() {
        Row() {
            Image(painter = painterResource(id = dice[0]), contentDescription = "Dice", modifier = Modifier
                .border(if (isSelected[0]) 2.dp else (-1).dp, Color.Black)
                .clickable { onClick(0) })
```

ViewModel:

```
class DicesViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(DicesModel())
    val uiState: StateFlow<DicesModel> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    fun isSelectedBehavior(index: Int = 0)
    {
        val list = DicesModel().isSelected
        list[index] = !list[index]
        _uiState.value = DicesModel(isSelected = list)
        Log.d("ViewModel","$list")
    }
}
```

Here are the logs from Run tab (the only one Log.d() is a few lines above).

> D/ViewModel: [true, false, false, false, false, false] // click on image - border appears
> D/ViewModel: [true, false, false, false, false, false] // click on image - nothing change (it will set first elemnt to false)
> D/ViewModel: [true, false, false, false, false, false] // click on image - nothing change (it will set first elemnt to false)
> D/ViewModel: [false, false, false, false, false, false] // click to button - border disappears
> D/ViewModel: [true, false, false, false, false, false] // // click on image - border appears

And data class DicesModel:

```
data class DicesModel(
    val isSelected : MutableList<Boolean> = mutableListOf(false, false, false, false, false, false)
)
```

I want to add or disable border after every click

Comment: You’re passing the same list instance back into the state so the state sees it as not having changed because it is comparing the same instance to itself to see if it has a new one. State cannot detect changes within mutable classes.

Comment: So what I have to do in my code?

Comment: Avoid MutableList altogether in your model class. Create new lists when you have changes.